# Javascript: How can I make a filter for a list like this?

Tags: javascript, class, filter

I'm a totally noob in Javascript so I have to ask you guys, how can I make this:

I have 3 checkboxex like this:

```
<ul class="bottom">
    <li><input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="large" /><label>Large</label></li>
    <li><input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="medium" /><label>Medium</label></li>
    <li><input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="small" /><label>Small</label></li>
</ul>
```

and then I have a list like this:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <ul class="row-1">
        <li class="full" data-type="large">
            <div class="onet-display">
                <?php if ($image = $post->get('image.src')): ?>
                    <a class="onet-display-block" href="<?= $view->url('@blog/id', ['id' => $post->id]) ?>"><img class="onet-thumb" src="<?= $image ?>" alt="<?= $post->get('image.alt') ?>"></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                <h1 class="onet-thumb-title"><a href="<?= $view->url('@blog/id', ['id' => $post->id]) ?>"><?= $post->title ?></a></h1>
                <div class="uk-margin"><?= $post->excerpt ?: $post->content ?></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="half" data-type="medium">...</li>
        <li class="full" data-type="small">...</li>
        <li class="half" data-type="large">...</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

And now I'd like to make something like a filter. I'd like to add a `class="showItem/hideItem"` to the `<li>` elements and the class changes to `"showItem"` as soon as the `<input value="large/medium/small">` is active.

I hope someone understand what I'd mean and sorry for my bad english.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to hide/show but you can change

`lis[j].style.display = this.checked ? "" : "none";`

to

`lis[j].className = this.checked ? "showItem" : "hideItem";`

if needed

**Plain JS**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var filter = document.querySelectorAll(".filter");
  for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
    filter[i].onclick = function() {
      var filter = document.querySelectorAll(".filter");
      for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li[data-type='" + this.value + "']");
        for (var j = 0; j < lis.length; j++) {
          lis[j].style.display = this.checked ? "" : "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom">
  <li>
    <input class="filter" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="large" />
    <label>Large</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="filter" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="medium" />
    <label>Medium</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="filter" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="small" />
    <label>Small</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="main-menu">
  <ul class="row-1">
    <li class="full" data-type="large">Large 1</li>
    <li class="half" data-type="medium">Medium 1</li>
    <li class="full" data-type="small">Small 1</li>
    <li class="half" data-type="large">Large 2</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".filter").on("click",function() {
    $(".filter").each(function() {
      $("li[data-type='"+this.value+"']").toggle(this.checked);
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bottom">
    <li><input class="filter" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="large" /><label>Large</label></li>
    <li><input class="filter" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="medium" /><label>Medium</label></li>
    <li><input class="filter" checked="true" type="checkbox" value="small" /><label>Small</label></li>
</ul>

<ul class="main-menu">
    <ul class="row-1">
        <li class="full" data-type="large">Large 1</li>
        <li class="half" data-type="medium">Medium 1</li>
        <li class="full" data-type="small">Small 1</li>
        <li class="half" data-type="large">Large 2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed :).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use plain javascript then...

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

function showhide() {

  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="' + this.value + '"]');
  for (var j = 0; j < elems.length; j++) {
    elems[j].classList.toggle("hide");
  }

}

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', showhide);

}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom">
  <li>
    <input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="large" />
    <label>Large</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="medium" />
    <label>Medium</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input checked="true" type="checkbox" value="small" />
    <label>Small</label>
  </li>
</ul>
and then I have a list like this:

<ul class="main-menu">
  <ul class="row-1">
    <li class="full" data-type="large">1</li>
    <li class="half" data-type="medium">2</li>
    <li class="full" data-type="small">3</li>
    <li class="half" data-type="large">4</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```